# How to write negation of an 'AND' statement in logic

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

Suppose the given proposition is:
"Zach blocks emails and texts from Jennifer"

Where,
P implies "Zach blocks emails from Jennifer".
Q implies "Zach blocks texts from Jennifer".

So it's P AND Q in logic.

Now we want to find its negation. So what I found as it's negation is:
"Zach does not block emails from Jennifer, or Zach does not block texts from Jennifer "

Now it is !P OR !Q which I can understand to be true since !(P AND Q) is equivalent to !P OR !Q.

But what if I write it as:
1. "Zach does not block emails and texts from Jennifer".
2. "It is not the case that Zach blocks the emails and texts from Jennifer".

What really confuses me is the statement 1 and 2  seems more like !P AND Q.

But then what I think !P AND Q can be more accurately written as:
3. "Zach does not block emails from Jennifer, and Zach block texts from Jennifer."
4. "It's not the case that Zach blocks the  emails from Jennifer, and Zach blocks the  texts from Jennifer."

Now my question are:
A. What is more accurate way to write !(P AND Q)?
B. Can it be written as statement 1 and 2?

Comment: The "and" in human speech might be not equivalent to the "and" in logic. So, the statement "Zach blocks emails and texts from Jennifer" means actually "Zach blocks emails from Jennifer" OR "Zach blocks texts from Jennifer" - cause the intersection of "emails" and "texts" is empty

Comment: What! I am unable to analyse.. And I should think this may create unreliable situation at times. Can u please explain why this and leads to OR in logic ..thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: If there were a perfect mapping from English to logic, we wouldn't need programming languages (or symbolic notation for logic), we would never have misunderstandings, we would never have arguments, there would be no need for judges or lawyers. The fact that we do have all those things shows that there is no perfect mapping from English to logic.